# How to get a popover from a popover in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-popover

I tried below code which i am not getting the second popup, My approach has some problem it seems and i am not getting idea to get second popup...

```js
$(function() {
    $(".pendingList, .pendings").popover();
 });
```

```css
.icon3{
 background: url('http://blog.flattr.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/stackoverflow.png') 1px 1px no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="icon3 pendingList" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" 
             data-content="<a href='#' class='pendings' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='click' data-html='true' data-placement='bottom' 
            data-content='test' >Pending(5)</a>"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this as well, https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/5uk7z38b/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code didn't work because  element doesn't exist when you execute popover method. Try code below, it works fine !

```js
$(function() {
    $(".pendingList").popover();
    $('.pendingList').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
      $(".pendings").popover();
    });
 });
```

```css
.icon3{
 background: url('http://blog.flattr.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/stackoverflow.png') 1px 1px no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="icon3 pendingList" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-content="<a href='#' class='pendings' data-toggle='popover' data-trigger='click' data-html='true' data-placement='bottom' data-content='test' >Pending(5)</a>"></div>
```